# Bootstrap nav : going to next line instead of pushing the nav's content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm creating a website with Boottrap, and I'm struggling with this (I'm kinda new to Flexbox and I think it will be linked to it) :

- I want each of my menu items to be on a single line (I managed to do that with white-space: nowrap;)
- I want my nav items to go on a second line when there is no space left

I'm struggling with the second option. Currently, when I have too many menu items, the content is pushed to the right and goes out of its container.

I'd want the nev elements to go to the line, while maintaining my Brand Name to the upper right.

Here's what it's doing now :
[image]

And here's what's I'm trying to do :
[image]
The test code is visible here : https://codepen.io/captain_torche/pen/PoPxwQj

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">First element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Second element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Third element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Fourth element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Fifth element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Sixth element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Seventh element</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Brand</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `flex-wrap` property.

It defines whether the flex items are forced in a single line or can be flowed into multiple lines.

The default value is `no-wrap` forcing the element (your list here) to display on a single line.

So for your need to make multiple line, you need to use the `wrap` value and it's easily made with Bootstrap 4 class `flex-wrap` on the list you want to go to next line.

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto  flex-wrap">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">First element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Second element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Third element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Fourth element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Fifth element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Sixth element</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Seventh element</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Brand</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a LOT ! That was exactly what I needed.